# terraform API Gateway V2 With Cloudfront 301/403 response depending on viewer_protocol_policy

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I can see loads of fun and games with 301/403 but no solutions, I have checked the logs and the request is not hitting the api gateway, no entries at all.  I am moving the api gateway from another domain so its all proven to work.  Curl to the end point results in 301 permanent move.  The frontend is at [www.xxxx.com](http://www.xxxx.com) and I want the api gateway to be assigned xxxx.com/api var.site_domain = xxxx.com

What determines 403/301: viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only" = 403, viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https" = 301

Using the AWS generated gateway url, the end points respond as designed

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>CloudFront</center>
</body>
</html>

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "XXXXXX" {
  domain_name = "api.${var.site_domain}"

  domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }
}


   resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "dist" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.site.website_endpoint
    origin_id   = aws_s3_bucket.site.id
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = replace(aws_apigatewayv2_stage.lambda.invoke_url, "/^https?://([^/]*).*/", "$1")
    origin_id   = "apigw"
    origin_path = "/serverless_lambda_stage"

    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = 80
      https_port             = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "https-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  aliases = [
    var.site_domain, "www.${var.site_domain}"
  ]

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = aws_s3_bucket.site.id
    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
    viewer_protocol_policy = "allow-all"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 5 * 60
    max_ttl                = 60 * 60
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/api/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "apigw"

    default_ttl = 0
    min_ttl     = 0
    max_ttl     = 0

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      headers      = ["Origin"]
      cookies {
        forward = "all"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"
  }


resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "lambda" {
  name          = "serverless_lambda_gw"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  cors_configuration {
    allow_origins = ["https://www.XXXX.com",
      "https://XXXX.com",
      # "http://localhost:3000"
    ]
    allow_methods = ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"]
    allow_headers = ["content-type"]
    max_age       = 300
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = var.site_domain
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "cdn" {
  name = "cdn.${var.site_domain}"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "api_main" {
  name = "api.${var.site_domain}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cdn-ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "cdn.${var.site_domain}"
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = aws_route53_zone.cdn.name_servers
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api-ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "api.${var.site_domain}"
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = aws_route53_zone.api_main.name_servers
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validations" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  count           = length(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options)

  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_name, count.index)
  type    = element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_type, count.index)
  records = [element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_value, count.index)]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api_picturethis" {
  name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_picturethis.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.api_main.zone_id

  alias {
    name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_picturethis.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api_picturethis.domain_name_configuration[0].hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Comment: What value does `var.site_domain` have?

Comment: Not sure if it matters for API Gateway v2, but is it a private API?

Comment: What type of API is that, HTTP or REST?

Comment: Ok, so I have two more questions: is there a Route53 record and are there any errors?

Comment: ERRORS viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only" = 403, viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https" = 301, added route53 records, 
Qs answers ## HTTP protocol type ## var.site_domain = XXXX.com ##not private API

Comment: ** Update ** since api gateway includes cloudfront I went with a sub domain, I was fronting my site with cloudflare which I only found examples of DNS to a cloudfront instance, cloudfunctions on the viewer-request may be a solution but examples I found  relied on the path_pattern approach